# Exclude folder from storage booster deletion?

Tags: applications, samsung, internal-storage

My samsung phone has this storage booster feature which deletes cache and unnecessary files daily but it has some caveats. There is a game that can't function without data files which are being deleted daily by the storage booster which results in me downloading massive files everyday.

Is there a way to exclude the app or game from the storage booster?